# Testing/watchdog SELECT rights in SQL Server without consuming server resources

Tags: sql, sql-server, watchdog

I am setting up a watch dog service to check if I can successfully login and run a `SELECT` on a certain database schema.

Basically I need to check if server is up, connection is operational, account can log in and account has `SELECT` permissions.

How to achieve this test with a query with minimum resource use on server side?

Is there something like a ''no operation'' command?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 0 Col1 FROM MyTable` maybe?  I think that'd be quicker than validating permissions for the account.  Drawback would be if the table changed or disappeared.

Comment: `Select column from table where 1=0` perhaps?

Comment: Or to not return a recordset you could do `declare @x int; select @x=col from table where 1=0`

Comment: Actually, all 3 of those return the same execution plan

Comment: For me these can be answers :)

Comment: a pointer for validating permissions for the account?@squillman

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83474/verify-if-user-has-read-access-to-a-table